# Pre-event handler - IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

I would like to trap the file upload event in IBM Connections, and take some actions. If a particular criteria gets satisfied, the file should be stored within the system, or else should be rejected with a message.

For this, I was exploring the IBM Connections SPI ( Pre-Event Handler hooks ). I have followed the necessary steps required as per the document to create the jar, deploy and change the configurations, but it seems that my code doesn't get called, when a file is uploaded into Connections.

Not sure, where lies the issue, as I don't get any errors too.

PS: I tried the Post Event handler hook and it worked successfully.

**Following are the snippets**

```
public class PreHandlerEvents implements PreEventHandler{
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(MutableEvent arg0) throws EventHandlerException {

        String content = "This is the content to write into file";
        File file = new File("filenamePre.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

events-config.xml

---

```
<preHandler enabled="true" name="PreHandlerEvents" class="com.connections.PreHandlerEvents">
        <subscriptions>
            <subscription source="*" type="*" eventName="*"/>
        </subscriptions>
    </preHandler>
</preHandlers>
```

Comment: Same for me. Both I and a customer of ours independentely tried to get the preeventhandler to work, but neither of us managed. The Posteventhandler did work completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather than a `PreEventHandler`, you could use an `EventHandler` instead in your `<preHandler .../>`?

Example code:

```
public class CustomEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    public void init() throws EventHandlerInitException {}

    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) throws EventHandlerException {
        System.out.println(" +++ Event: " + event.getName());
    }
}
```